# Responsive dropdown menu : Selectnav and images in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [selectnav](https://github.com/lukaszfiszer/selectnav.js) to convert inline menu (ul) to a select drop-down menu on mobile devices.It's good for exclusive text menu, but i get an issue when i use an image for link into inline menu.The select provide an empty choice...
This is my menu code:

```
<ul class="horizontal-nav" id="subnav"><li><img alt="Provence Formation" src="../images/logo-Pf-sites-lycees.jpg" style="width: 335px; height: 55px;" /></li><li><a href="/node/73" title="Recrutement de l'association">Ecole Directe</a></li><li><a href="/node/149" title="Inscription dans les lycées">OBII</a></li><li><a href="/node/23" title="Nous contacter par message électronique">Contact </a></li></ul>
```

Does exist a way to tell to selectnav to use the alt or title attribute of the image ?

thanks

Comment: nobody knows ? I don't find any information about this use case.

Comment: Selectnav takes text from an anchor element to create your `select` element options.

What you could do is wrap the image in an anchor and use an image replacement technique, there is a list available at CodePen https://css-tricks.com/the-image-replacement-museum/

Comment: it's a way.Before I thought using javascript to replace imagee by one of  it's attributes ( title or alt) when the menu transform himself into select nav.

Comment: I'm trying to do the anchor technique , so I add an anchor to my image like this : `<li class="logo"><a href="http://provence-formation.fr" name="pf" target="_blank" title="Provence Formation"><img alt="Provence Formation" src="http://www.provence-formation.fr/sites/all/themes/Cyrano_PF/images/logo-Pf-sites-lycees.jpg" style="width: 152px; height: 25px;" title="Provence Formation" /></a></li>`  but on mobile the select option is still empty..

Comment: with an image background on the <li> and text-indent it works :)

Comment: Glad you managed to figure it out in the end :)